# Logger.getLogger(class_name.class.getName()) leads to NullPointerException

Tags: java, logging, static

The problem is that Logger is not initialized using  `Logger.getLogger(class_name.class.getName())` approach.
You can see the codes below. I marked the line which leads to the exception.
I must note that I tried without static `setLevel` block as well.

```
// File that contains logger
public class Experience {

private final static Experience INSTANCE = new Experience(); 
private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Experience.class.getName());

private MainFrame main_frame;

static {
    LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
    }

public static Experience getInstance()
    {
    return INSTANCE;
    }

private Experience()
    {
    try
        {
        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/log.txt");
        fh.setFormatter(new XPLogFormatter());
        LOGGER.addHandler(fh); // NULLPOINTEREXCEPION HERE
        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


// Just a loader
public class Loader
{
public static void main(String args[])
    {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
                {
                MainFrame main_frame = new MainFrame();
                }
        });
    }
}


// Stripped down version of main frame
public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{
private Experience XP;

public MainFrame()
    {
    super();
    XP = Experience.getInstance(this);
    }
}


// Modified formatter
public class XPLogFormatter extends Formatter
{
@Override
public String format(LogRecord record)
    {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(1000);
    buf.append(formatMessage(record));
    return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me what exactly leads to this error?

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder. There is almost never a good reason to use StringBuffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trouble is that these two static variable initializers are executed in textual order:

```
private final static Experience INSTANCE = new Experience(); 
public final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Experience.class.getName());
```

So when the first line calls the constructor, which includes this:

```
LOGGER.addHandler(fh);
```

... `LOGGER` is still null.

The *simplest* fix would be to just reverse the order of the declarations... but another, clearer alternative would be to do it all in the static initializer:

```
private final static Experience INSTANCE;
public final static Logger LOGGER;

static {
    LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Experience.class.getName());
    LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
    INSTANCE = new Experience();
}
```

(Out of interest, do you *really* want the logger to be public?)

Comment: Ah, that public was simply an edit that I forgot to change back ;).

Answer (score 0):

Because you have never defined a Logger with the name "Experience". When you call getLogger(String) it looks for a defined logger with that name. Try just doing Logger.getLogger(Experience.class), that should get you the logger for Experience

Comment: Alex, the problem was in the textual order (see Jon's comment above). Also, there are 2 versions of getLogger method (at least in Java 6) and both have String parameters. Therefore, Logger.getLogger(Experience.class) won't compile.